# Отловить завершение консольной программы, потоки и join

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  //Какой то код...

  allIP.stream().forEach((localIP) -> 
  {
     getInfoFromRemotePC gr = new getInfoFromRemotePC(localIP); 

     try { gr.thread.join(); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
  });
}
System.out.println("MAIN FINISHED");
```

Проблема в следующем: Запускаеться скажем 50 потоков, которые вызываются getInfoFromRemotePC. И главный поток не ждёт завершения всех процессов и завершается. Процессы уже сами отрабатывают и закрываются. Если не использовать join то программа отрабатывает быстро, но не могу отловить завершение главного потока. Если использовать join, то могу отловить завершение, но программа начинает очень долго отрабатывать. Может я не правильно использую join? Как можно отловить завершение главного потока без больших задержек?

```
public final class getInfoFromRemotePC implements Runnable
{
   String ip;
   Thread thread;

   getInfoFromRemotePC(String ip)
   {
      this.ip = ip.trim();
      thread = new Thread(this, ip.trim());
      thread.start();

   }

   @Override
    public void run() 
    {
      //Код потока  

    }
```

}

Comment: не лучше получить `Thread`, и только потом сджоинить их вместе ?   под словом главный поток вы имеете ввиду  "main" так сказать?

Comment: Да, именно main. И как к main приджойнить порожденные потоки?

Comment: https://ideone.com/CrKZDe проблем не вижу. main ждет всех остальных. что у вас внутри run()?

Comment: Там код опрашивающий локальные ПК. Подключается по ssh, отправляет команду, получает ответ и выводит.

Comment: Получается что код написан верно, но т.к в потоке идет длительная задача, то main и ожидает пока все не отработают? Без join отрабатывает шустро и правильно.

Comment: в конце run выводи сообщение о том, какой поток завершился, как в моем примере. а в начале какой запустился.  приложи реззультат к вопросу и скажи общее количество allIP

Comment: Добавил сообщения. И вот что получается. При использовании join потоки стартуют по очереди, и следующий поток не стартует пока не завершился предыдущий. Я подозреваю что это неправильно. Они должны стартовать все вместе.  Быстрее всего проблема в коде что привел в заголовке. У меня получается что поток сам и ждет когда завершится. А как сделать что бы главный поток ждал завершения остальных?    @Senior Automator общее количество allIP динамическое. может быть любым.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48658/discussion-between-senior-automator-and-kamenev-d).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<getInfoFromRemotePC> threads = new ArrayList<>(); // чтобы запомнить все потоки 
    Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4","5").stream().forEach((localIP) ->{
        threads.add(new getInfoFromRemotePC(localIP));
    });

    threads.forEach(f -> f.join()); // склеить потоки 

    System.out.println("MAIN FINISHED");

}
введите сюда код

public static final class getInfoFromRemotePC implements Runnable
{
    String ip;
    Thread thread;

    getInfoFromRemotePC(String name)
    {
        ip = name;
        thread = new Thread(this, name);
        thread.start();

    }

    public void join(){
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println(ip);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        System.out.println(ip + " FINISHED");


    }
}
```

вывод

```
2
3
4
5
1
2 FINISHED
3 FINISHED
4 FINISHED
1 FINISHED
5 FINISHED
MAIN FINISHED
```